# Compare semicolon separated data in 2 files using shell script

Tags: perl, unix, shell

I have some data (separated by semicolon) with close to 240 rows in a text file `temp1`.
`temp2.txt` stores 204 rows of data (separated by semicolon).

I want to:

1. Sort the data in both files by `field1`, i.e. the first data field in every row.
2. Compare the data in both files and redirect the rows that are not equal in separate files.

Sample data:

```
temp1.txt
1000xyz400100xyzA00680xyz0;19722.83;19565.7;157.13;11;2.74;11.00
1000xyz400100xyzA00682xyz0;7210.68;4111.53;3099.15;216.95;1.21;216.94
1000xyz430200xyzA00651xyz0;146.70;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00

temp2.txt
1000xyz400100xyzA00680xyz0;19722.83;19565.7;157.13;11;2.74;11.00
1000xyz400100xyzA00682xyz0;7210.68;4111.53;3099.15;216.95;1.21;216.94
```

The sort command I'm using:

```
sort -k1,1 temp1 -o temp1.tmp
sort -k1,1 temp2 -o temp2.tmp
```

I'd appreciate if someone could show me how to redirect only the missing/mis-matching rows into two separate files for analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the difference as described at http://www.pixelbeat.org/cmdline.html#sets

```
sort -t';' -k1,1 temp1 temp1 temp2 | uniq -u > only_in_temp2
sort -t';' -k1,1 temp1 temp2 temp2 | uniq -u > only_in_temp1
```

Notes:

- Use join rather than uniq, as shown at the link above if you want to compare only particular fields
- If the first field is fixed width then you don't need the -t';' -k1,1 params above

Comment: If you're sorting by field 1, do you need to specify the field at all?

Comment: Yes, as I commented you need to specify the field boundaries iff the fields are not fixed width

Comment: Excellent solution. Thanks to everyone who jotted down their inputs.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
cat temp1 temp2 | sort -k1,1 -o tmp
# mis-matching/missing rows:
uniq -u tmp
# matching rows:
uniq -d tmp
```

Comment: You can pipe into uniq and eliminate the tmp file, also useless use of `cat` - sort can take multiple files: `sort temp1.txt temp2.txt | uniq -u`

Comment: temporary file was there just to use the sorted data twice, for `uniq -u` and `uniq -d`, and `cat` is not required, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [the comm command](http://ss64.com/bash/comm.html).

Answer (score 0):

using gawk, and outputting lines in file1 that is not in file2

```
awk -F";" 'FNR==NR{  a[$1]=$0;next }
( ! ( $1 in a)  ) {  print $0 > "afile.txt" }' file2 file1
```

interchange the order of file2 and file to output line in file2 that is not in file1